# Error cambio de estado button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo un tabla llamada user donde contiene uno de sus campos llamado status, dicho campo lo utilizo dentro de un panel de administrador el cual al pulsar el button debe cambiar el status que tengo definido como `inhabilitado=0` y `habilitado=1`, mi problema es que cambia el status solo cuando el usuario tiene status 1 y necesito que funcione de ambas maneras ya que el administrador necesita habilitar a los usuarios que quiera para que estos puedan acceder al sistema. Adjunto el código.

```
$(document).ready(function name(params) {
    console.log('Jqueri is working');

    $(document).on('click', '.changeStatus', function (e) {
     console.log("this", $(this)); //obtienes el bottom que fue clickeado
    let element = $(this)[0];
    let status = $(element).attr('buttonStatus');

    console.log('primer', status);
    status = !status;
    console.log('segundo', status);
    const id = $(element).attr('buttonId');
    $.post('../controllers/changeStatus.php', {id: id , status: status}, function(response) {
        console.log(response); 
    })

    });
});
```

---

```
<?php
                                require_once '../DBconect.php';

                                $select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT id,name,email,role,status FROM user");
                                $select_stmt->execute();

                                while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                {

                                    $status=$row['status'];
                                    $color = 'success';
                                    $title = 'Habilitar';
                                    if($status==1) {
                                        $color = 'danger';
                                        $title = 'Inhabilitar'; 
                                    }
                                    $class_name="btn btn-lg btn-$color";
                                    
                                ?>
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row["role"]; ?></td>
                                        <td>*******</td>
                                        <td width="1%"><button class="changeStatus <?php echo $class_name; ?>" buttonId="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" buttonStatus="<?php echo $status; ?>"><span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo $title ?></span></button></td>
                                        
                                    </tr>
```

Comment: podrías colocar tu `button`, creo que estas cambiando el status de forma correcta, pero este lo obtienes del botón por lo que si no cambias el estado del atributo siempre te cambiara solo una vez, podrías colocar ese pedazo de código.

Comment: Añadi la parte del codigo del boton debajo

Comment: Creo que sería más simple usar un checkbox para esto en vez de un botón. Con el checkbox simplemente cuando lo marques significará que está habilitado y cuando lo desmarques que está deshabilitado.

Answer (score 0):

Me referia al hecho de obtener el dato del input, este llega como texto, si tu cambias 'true' cambiara a false, pero 'false' no cambiara a true, porque obtienes un texto, si deseas puedes usar el siguiente if ternario:

```
status = status == 'true' ? false : true;
```

Adicionalmente estoy volviendo a setear el valor del `buttonStatus`, para al hacer nuevamente el envio este tenga un valor contrario.

```js
$(document).ready(function name(params) {
  console.log('Jqueri is working');

  $(document).on('click', '.changeStatus', function(e) {
    let element = $(this)[0];
    let status = $(element).attr('buttonStatus');

    console.log('primer', status);
    status = status == 'true' ? false : true;
    $(element).attr('buttonStatus', status);
    console.log('segundo', status);
    const id = $(element).attr('buttonId');
    $.post('../controllers/changeStatus.php', {
      id: id,
      status: status
    }, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td width="1%"><button class="changeStatus 1" buttonId="1" buttonStatus="false"><span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true">Cambia de status</span></button></td>
```